# Sklearn Target Data - Only Integer Scalars Can be Converted to A Scalar Index

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, text-classification

I am following this [tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) to generate the plot confusion matrix, based on this data:

```
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), shuffle=True, random_state=42)
twenty_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), shuffle=True, random_state=42)

vect = CountVectorizer()
train_vect = vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
test_vect = vect.transform(twenty_test.data)

mnb_clf = MultinomialNB().fit(train_vect, twenty_train.target)
mnb_prd = mnb_clf.predict(test_vect)

plot_confusion_matrix(twenty_test.target, mnb_prd, twenty_test.target_names)
```

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes)
    classes = classes[unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)]
```

In plot_confusion_matrix function, I have to pass the true target of test data (twenty_test.target), predicted target of test data (mnb_prd, I am using Naive Bayes Classifier), and the true target names of test data (twenty_test.target).

However, in redefining variable classes, it returned error only integer scalars. I think I already set the passing variables right based on the tutorial, so maybe there is something that needs to be add. 
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

**THE STACK TRACE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-32abf4cde70d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Literatures/Text Mining/Exercises/text_mining_assignment.py', wdir='C:/Users/Literatures/Text Mining/Exercises')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Literatures/Text Mining/Exercises/text_mining_assignment.py", line 115, in <module>
    plot_confusion_matrix(twenty_test.target, mnb_prd, twenty_test.target_names, cm_mnb, 'Naive Bayes Confusion matrix')

  File "C:/Users/Literatures/Text Mining/Exercises/text_mining_assignment.py", line 32, in plot_confusion_matrix
    classes = classes[unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Please post the complete the stack trace. Also what is `unique_labels` ?

Comment: hi, I already add the traceback, and about unique_labels, it is a module from multiclass sklearn to return an array with unique variables